# Loop back to initial prompt of a nested If statement without breaking program: Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm writing a program in Python that asks a user what toppings they would like on their pizza, as shown below.

```
print("PIZZA TOPPINGS: \n mushrooms \n pineapple \n anchovies \n pepperoni \n sausage \n extra cheese \n")

toppings = ["pepperoni", "ham", "pineapple", "mushrooms", "sausage", "anchovies", "extra cheese"]

your_toppings = []

maxLengthList = 3

while len(your_toppings) < maxLengthList:
        item = input("Add up to 3 toppings: ").lower()

        if item == "ham":
                print("Sorry, out of ham")
                continue

        elif item in toppings:
                print("Adding " + item) 

        elif item == "":
                ans = input("Are you sure you don't want to add any more toppings? Y/N ").lower() #this is the line I'm trying to loop back to

                if ans == "yes" or ans == "y":
                        break
                elif ans == "no" or ans == "n":
                        continue
                else:
                        print("Please answer y/n")
                        #trying to loop back to Y/N prompt
        else:
                print("Not an option")
                continue

        your_toppings.append(item)

if len(your_toppings) > 0:
        print("Your toppings:  " + ', '.join(your_toppings))
else:
        print("No toppings for you!")
```

The part I've been stuck at is inside the nested If statement (see the 2nd comment), if the user does not answer with the required y/n. I'm trying to figure out how I can loop back to the input prompt, "Are you sure you don't want to add any more toppings? Y/N" until they respond with y/n.

I did try to use a nested while loop before the ans = input line, but that breaks the program as answering with y/n does not break/continue in the original while loop (i.e. back to the topping prompt), but in the inner while loop instead.

Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this?

I'm still pretty new to Python so I'm playing around primarily with these If statements/While loops at this point, so I understand my program may start to look messy with so much nesting. I am willing to modify it using another angle if that would accomplish the same thing.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your nested while loop, break from the loop when you get a correct yes or no response. Then outside the loop, check whether it is yes or no and break.

Better yet, make a function that asks your yes/no question and doesn’t return until you get a yes/no answer. Then call that from your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with the nexted loop, but maybe just make it a small inner loop to check for validity. Something like this:

```
    elif item == "":
            while True:
                ans = input("Are you sure you don't want to add any more toppings? Y/N ").lower() #this is the line I'm trying to loop back to
                if ans not in ['yes', 'y', 'no', 'n']:
                    print("Please answer y/n")
                else:
                    break

            if ans == "yes" or ans == "y":
                break
            else:
                continue
```